# /usr/local/bin/qtpasswd: No such file or directory

Tags: linux, darwin

I'm Trying to install Darwin Streaming Server on virtualbox ubuntu desktop amd64.
Running the darwin setup at the end gives this

```
./Install: line 406: /usr/local/bin/qtpasswd: No such file or directory
./Install: line 406: /usr/local/bin/qtpasswd: No such file or directory
Setup Complete!
```

And When I hit the url on the browser it says
"Server is not running please start it before attempting to administer it".

Comment: Google that. You are not the only person with the problem.

Comment: Now I've simply installed the Darwin server on ubuntu 10.04.
This is working fine.

Answer (score 1):

you can post your complete installing log.
i run into the same error prompt as yours while i build my Darwin Stream Server-5.5.5 source on centOS6.5 .

you can modify part of the installing script "Install" (about line 191)

```
# Add the unprivileged user qtss as the server's run user
echo "Creating unprivileged user to run the server = \"qtss\"."
if [ $INSTALL_OS = "Linux" ]; then
    /usr/sbin/useradd -M qtss > /dev/null 2>&1
else
    /usr/sbin/useradd qtss > /dev/null 2>&1
fi
```

into

```
# Add the unprivileged user qtss as the server's run user
echo "Creating unprivileged user to run the server = \"qtss\"."
if [ $INSTALL_OS = "Linux" ]; then

groupadd -r qtss

/usr/sbin/useradd -M -r -g qtss qtss > /dev/null 2>&1

else
    /usr/sbin/useradd qtss > /dev/null 2>&1
fi
```

then try to run ./Install again.
it works for me.

make sure you have installed perl before you run ./Install